# How do you create a copy of an UIImageView instance?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, copy

How do I create a copy of an UIImageView instance that can be manipulated independently of the first instance?

I've tried `UIImageView *tempCopy = [instance copy]` but it crashes. Is there another way?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the UIImage it represents?

Comment: The UIImageView is a series of UIButtons, can I treat them as a UIImage of the UIImageView?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It probably crashes because UIImageView doesn't conform to the [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) protocol. So do it yourself: instantiate a new UIImageView and set any property from your original that you find of interest.

Comment: Is there anyway to copy all the properties? What I'm copying is an extremely elaborate object

Comment: Howcome? It's only a few values you need to assign and you're done.

Comment: What I'm trying to copy are all the subviews, is there an easy way I don't know about?

Comment: That a different question... You could implement a copy routine for one UIView, and traverse recursively through the view tree using the `view.subViews` array, while checking the type of view for every node. Horrible solution. Why not create the thing twice in the first place?

Comment: The object interaction is complicated and I'm trying to simplify it, thanks though i'll need to find another way.

Answer (score 7):

`UIImageView` doesn't conform to `NSCopying`, but it does conform to `NSCoding`. Archive your view, and then de-archive it to get a brand new copy.

For the lazily inclined, this looks like:

```
NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imageView];
UIImageView *copy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: You're looking at roughly twice the time it takes to load a nib (assuming the nib is already in-memory, rather than on disk). Instantiation from a nib is basically just the second half of my answer, so you're only adding in the extra work of creating the archive

Comment: There you go, example added

Answer (score -1):

In answer to the response of Mike Abdullah... the question is that he needs to save all the subviews already existing in his image view...

the problem of using that approach is that the default implementation of NSCoding won't save those views... so he would have to override the method and provide deep coding (for those efforts he better conforms to NSCopying and perform the deep copy)

If all you need is a static image (the subviews don't provide interaction) i would recommend doing the following

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.rect.size);

[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *copyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
```

This will ensure that tue subviews get all saved as a static image...

if you need a copy that has the subviews that retain their interaction... this would not help you...

Greetings

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong on that front; `UIView`'s implementation of `NSCoding` includes all its sub-views

Comment: Thanks, you are right, i mistook deep copying with deep codying... thanks for the correction