# Cloning a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UIImageView:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "name")
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

// .. constraints to imageView

view.addSubview(imageView)
```

I am trying to create a duplicate copy of that same `imageView` and store it in another variable. I tried to use `NSKeyedArchiver` but it did not work, here is what I have:

```
extension UIView {
   func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

My goal is to have an imageView, `cloneImageView`, to be an exact duplicate of `imageView`

```
var cloneImageView = imageView.copyView()
```

Comment: Doesn't assigning imageView to secondImageView work?

Comment: @ManishMahajan that wouldn't work, this will set `secondImageView` to `imageView` and not create a new instance

Comment: I dont think `UIImageView` conform to `NSCoding` so you cant use `NSKeyedUnarchiver ` with it

Comment: what did you mean by cloning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a copy of an UIImageView instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621922/how-do-you-create-a-copy-of-an-uiimageview-instance)

Answer (score 1):

I think UIImageView doesn't conform to the NSCopying protocol. Because of that it will get crashed. So instantiate with a new UIImageView will be a solution.

[Please refer to this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621922/how-do-you-create-a-copy-of-an-uiimageview-instance)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy UIImageView and match all of the properties as well, like size, clipping, image aspect, opacity..etc , you should clone all this properties , I write extension for this solution that was in Objective C [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439234/how-to-clone-a-uiimageview)

but  to copy `UIImage` of `UImageView` you can use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` after convert it to row data  by `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

if you want to just clone  without store you can use copy()  Creates a copy of a bitmap image. new image with same scale and orientation

```
if  let image  = imageView.image , let bitmapCopy =  image.cgImage?.copy()  {
    let newImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: bitmapCopy, scale: image.scale, orientation:  image.imageOrientation)
 }
```

> Swift extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView{

    func clone() -> UIImageView{

        let locationOfCloneImageView = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        //x and y coordinates of where you want your image. (More specifically, the x and y coordinated of where you want the CENTER of your image to be)
        let cloneImageView = UIImageView(image: self.image)
        cloneImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        //same size as old image view
        cloneImageView.alpha = self.alpha
        //same view opacity
        cloneImageView.layer.opacity = self.layer.opacity
        //same layer opacity
        cloneImageView.clipsToBounds = self.clipsToBounds
        //same clipping settings
        cloneImageView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        //same BG color
        if let aColor = self.tintColor {
            self.tintColor = aColor
        }
        //matches tint color.
        cloneImageView.contentMode = self.contentMode
        //matches up things like aspectFill and stuff.
        cloneImageView.isHighlighted = self.isHighlighted
        //matches whether it's highlighted or not
        cloneImageView.isOpaque = self.isOpaque
        //matches can-be-opaque BOOL
        cloneImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = self.isUserInteractionEnabled
        //touches are detected or not
        cloneImageView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = self.isMultipleTouchEnabled
        //multi-touches are detected or not
        cloneImageView.autoresizesSubviews = self.autoresizesSubviews
        //matches whether or not subviews resize upon bounds change of image view.
        //cloneImageView.hidden = originalImageView.hidden;//commented out because you probably never need this one haha... But if the first one is hidden, so is this clone (if uncommented)
        cloneImageView.layer.zPosition = self.layer.zPosition + 1
        //places it above other views in the parent view and above the original image. You can also just use `insertSubview: aboveSubview:` in code below to achieve this.
        self.superview?.addSubview(cloneImageView)
        //adds this image view to the same parent view that the other image view is in.
        cloneImageView.center = locationOfCloneImageView
        //set at start of code.

        return cloneImageView
    }


}
```